# ASP.NET - User control filed value changes at every pageload

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a User control that contains three dropdownlists:for day,month and year. It's kind of a datepicker. It has a private field

```
private bool _isValidDate = false;
```

On dropdownlists the first items are "Day", "Month" and "Year". On SelectedIndexChanged event I check if all the selected indices are greater than 0 and if it's true I try to create a new DateTime object with values of the dropdownlists like such:

```
try
{ 
  DateTime date=new DateTime(int.Parse(ddlYear.SelectedItem),
                                ddlMonth.SelectedIndex,
                                ddlDay.SelectedIndex);
  _isValidDate=true;
}
catch {_isValidDate=false;}
```

On the form where I use this control before submitting I check for the IsValidDate property and if it's false I warn the user. The problem is the first time I set the correct date and press the button I don't get any warning as IsValidDate property is true but if I click it for the second time the IsValidDate property sets back to false and I get the warning although the date is valid. I know it's because everytime the page loads the _isValiddate filed of the control is set back to it's default value-false. How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property should be like this.

```
public Boolean IsValidDate 
{
    get
    {
        String CompleteDate = "YourYear" + "/" + "YourMonth" + "/" + "YourDay";
        DateTime Dt ;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(CompleteDate, out Dt))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```